# Javascript or jQuery version of Download attribute to work in firefox (it is working in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I search here on stackoverflow articles that HTML download attribute does not work in firefox so i try all solutions and i im unable to find solutio that works...i need to do multiple file download so i try this:

```
<a href="http://myurl/one.txt" download>download</a>
```

In Chrome it downloads file...in firefox it only opens and display txt file in browser...so how to force firefox to download file?

For multiple download files i use this:

```
function downloadAll(urls) {
     for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

    var link = document.createElement('a');

      link.setAttribute('download','Balance Sheet Year 2014-2015');
      link.style.display = 'none';

      document.body.appendChild(link);

      for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        link.setAttribute('href', urls[i]);
        link.click();
      }

      document.body.removeChild(link);*/
    }
```

And then calling it using:

```
downloadAll(['one.txt', 'second.db']);
```

In Chrome it works great..when i click on download button it downloads `one.txt` and `second.db` but in firefox it only opens one.txt and not download any of two files...how to fix this?

I im using Chrome for years and is fast and more standards user friendly but firefox i don't know great to fix this..and please don't give me minus points and comments like duplicate post..because i try all of them and none works in my environment...thanks

Comment: The download attribute is supported by Firefox since version 20 (current version 57), so maybe you should update your Firefox browser?

Comment: I im using 57.0.4 (64-bit) firefox lastest version

Comment: Firefox only allows users to download files of the same origin due to a security concern. The file must come from your own server or domain name, otherwise it will be opened in the browser. Are you sure that the file comes from your domain? Also try to add filename with extension like so `download="myfile.txt"`

Comment: Yes you are right..i use now same host as my index.php is hosted and it is downloading file..any trick in javascipt or jQuery to set header if is on another domain to download file? i use ftp:// to download txt and video file..so i cannot use same domain